# Installshield not installation prerqe (Framework 3.5)

Tags: installation, installshield

I am developing an app in Framework 3.5.
I would like Installshield to check if Framework 3.5 is already installed.
If it's not installed, i want it to download it from the internet and then install it.

On my App Data -> Redistributables,
I have Microsoft Framework 3.5 SP1 as a Installshield Prerqe.
It is "Installed Locally" and build location "Copy from source media".

I have Framework 3.5 as required for installation.

On Windows XP, it works fine.
It asks user to install Framework 3.5 if required.

On Windows 7, 8, 2008: even if Framework 3.5 is not installed. It does not ask user the download/install it. It only prompts them that the installation cannot continue because 3.5 is not installed.

Any idea on how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prereq provided is only valid pre Win 7.  Starting with Win7, .NET 3.5 is included as a windows component and cannot be installed using the prereq.  You have to use a DISM command to install the feature instead.   Starting with Win8, the .NET 3.5 bits aren't cached in the Windows installation media and it requires an internet connection to download from Windows Update during the DISM command.

Yes. I don't like it either.  Easiest thing to do from a deployment perspective is to allow installation if .NET 3.5 or 4.0 is installed and test your application to make sure it'll function on both CLR 2.0 and 4.0.

Comment: that would require breaking many Linq functions. Do you think that is really the easiest way ? (Not being sarcastic, it's an actual question). Many application of my do work in 2.0 but not all. However, there are many bugs running in 2.0

Comment: .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 are all CLR 2.0.  .NET 4.0/4.5 is CLR 4.0.  You're .NET 3.5 app should work on .NET 3.5, 4.0 or 4.5.